# Abelian and non-abelian group where $a^{3} = e$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I was asked to find a group where $a^{3} = e$ $ \forall a \in G$, G being the group. I came across the Heisenberg group(which from my understand is the group of all $3 \times 3$ matrices which has one along its diagonals and 0s in the bottom half, and real numbers in the top half). But when I multiplied such a matrix by itself 3 times, I did not land up with the identity matrix.

Can someone help me if my definition of Heisenberg group is wrong, and with helping me find abelian and non-abelian groups where if the elements are cubed, we get the identity?

Comment: The Heisenberg group in question here has entres in the integers modulo $3$, not in the real numbers.

Comment: Cyclic group of order $3$ and its direct powers are Abelian examples.

Comment: @MrSnake _some_ elements do, but not all (note the quantifier): the permutation $p\in S_3$ that swaps 1 and 2 doesn't satisfy $p^3=e$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Oh, excuse me. You are right, I missed the quantifier... I delete my comment above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The original Heisenberg group is the group you describe: the $3\times 3$ matrices of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & a & c\\
0 & 1 & b\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\tag{1}$$
with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$, which form a group under the usual matrix multiplication.

However, there is a generalization, and they are all generally known as "the Heisenberg group", and one is supposed to know which by context. Given any field $F$ (for example, the rationals, the complex numbers, the reals, the algebraic numbers, or a finite field of order $p$), you consider the matrices of the form $(1)$, but where now $0$, $1$, and $a,b,c$ are taken in the field $F$.

You should verify that these matrices form a group. In particular, if you take the entries in $\mathbb{F}_3=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, the integers modulo $3$, you obtain a nonabelian group of order $27$. (In general, taking them in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ gives you a nonabelian group of order $p^3$). You should verify that it has the property you want.

Comment: Hi Professor, just a quick question about the notation $\mathbb{Z}$ \ ${3\mathbb{Z}}$, does this mean all the factor groups of $3\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Anonymous: First, it's $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ (the integers modulo the multiples of $3$; the quotient of the integers by the ideal of multiples of $3$), not $\mathbb{Z}\setminus 3\mathbb{Z}$ (the integers with the multiples of $3$ **removed**). Second: it's the ring/field of integers modulo $3$ with modular addition and multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}_{3}$

$\mathbb{Z}_{3} \oplus\mathbb{Z}_{3}$

$\underbrace{\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3}_{n\text{ factors}}$

All are examples of abelian groups whose every non identity element has order 3.

What you have mentioned, Heisenberg Group has order $27$.

it is collection of all upper triangular matrices with diagonal
entries 1 (entries of upper half comes from integer modulo 3 ($\mathbb{Z}_3$).

Comment: *Please* use MathJax. *Again*, here's [the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Sir, I have no computer. Is it possible to use it from mobile phone?

Comment: Yes; it's just how you type the mathematics so that they render properly. It's almost exactly like typing in $\LaTeX$. If you can type a message of the length you clearly are able to, then you can type it up so that it renders properly. Have you honestly not noticed how pretty much *every other post* by *every other person* features Math is that is properly formatted, and not ascii art like yours?

Comment: Yes Sir, I have noticed. Using mathematical notation,any answer becomes more understandle to everyone.

Comment: @SwapnajitDas Are there any non-Abelian groups for which this holds?

Comment: Quite so. So please fix all your posts so far, and use it in the future.

Comment: Heisenberg group is non abelian satisfying given property